# Make new array that fills in missing values using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, lodash

I have an array of objects which have a property of `date` in milliseconds. Note that the first three objects have the same date, but a different `value`.

```
var data = [
{"date":"1420070400000","value":53,"lat":"41.8089","lon":"-88.0111","regType":"Client","jobRole":"Other"},
{"date":"1420070400000","value":376,"lat":"41.8089","lon":"-88.0111","regType":"Client","jobRole":"Other"},
{"date":"1420070400000","value":43,"lat":"41.8089","lon":"-88.0111","regType":"Client","jobRole":"Other"},
{"date":"1420156800000","value":410,"lat":"41.8089","lon":"-88.0111","regType":"Client","jobRole":"Other"},
{"date":"1420329600000","value":210,"lat":"41.8089","lon":"-88.0111","regType":"Client","jobRole":"Other"}
];
```

`console.log(data)` shows this for the first object:

```
date: "1420070400000"jobRole: "Other"lat: "41.8089"lon: "-88.0111"regType: "Client"value: 53
```

Then, I have a second array of dates in milliseconds covering all possible dates between the earliest and latest dates of the first array.

```
var earliestDate = 1420070400000;
var latestDate = 1420329600000;
var list = [];
for (var i = earliestDate; i <= latestDate; i += 86400000) {
    list.push(i);
}
```

And `console.log(list)` shows this for that array:

```
[1420070400000, 1420156800000, 1420243200000, 1420329600000]
```

Note that the third date `1420243200000` is a date that exists between the earliest and latest dates, but is not in the original array of objects. That original array does not include every date in the range.

I want a resulting array of objects (like the first one), but with every date in the range. So, when a date was not present in the original array, now it is and it has new values assigned to its other properties.

I am trying to use `_.find` in lodash.

```
var newData = list.map(function(dateValue) {
    return _.find(data, { date: dateValue }) || {date: dateValue, value: 0, lat: "no lat value", lon: "no lon value", regType: "no regType value", jobRole: "no jobRole value" };
});
```

However, `console.log(newData);` shows this (here's the first object for example), which is assigning the new values to an existing date, which I don't want:

```
date: 1420070400000jobRole: "no jobRole value"lat: "no lat value"lon: "no lon value"regType: "no regType value"value: 0
```

Also, it is returning only 4 objects when there were originally five. What am I missing?

Here's the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/airwwwave/y8mbhub7/1/) where you can inspect element. Thanks!

Comment: You've provided the wrong JsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/airwwwave/y8mbhub7/1/

Comment: Oops, sorry. Just updated the link to remove the "embedded/result/" part at the end of the link. Thank you. Hopefully now if you inspect element on the page, you can see stuff in the console. Apologies.

Comment: I should also say that I'm not married to using lodash, that was just what I tried based on this tutorial: http://www.d3noob.org/2014/04/adding-in-zero-values-into-time-series.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this your desired result

```
[ { date: '1420070400000',
    value: 53,
    lat: '41.8089',
    lon: '-88.0111',
    regType: 'Client',
    jobRole: 'Other' },
  { date: '1420070400000',
    value: 376,
    lat: '41.8089',
    lon: '-88.0111',
    regType: 'Client',
    jobRole: 'Other' },
  { date: '1420070400000',
    value: 43,
    lat: '41.8089',
    lon: '-88.0111',
    regType: 'Client',
    jobRole: 'Other' },
  { date: '1420156800000',
    value: 410,
    lat: '41.8089',
    lon: '-88.0111',
    regType: 'Client',
    jobRole: 'Other' },
  { date: '1420329600000',
    value: 410,
    lat: '41.8089',
    lon: '-88.0111',
    regType: 'Client',
    jobRole: 'Other' },
  { date: '1420243200000',
    value: 0,
    lat: 'no lat value',
    lon: 'no lon value',
    regType: 'no regType value',
    jobRole: 'no jobRole value' } ]
```

here you can use **_.find**

first, create a list of all dates you want to make sure appear in your data. then **forEach** to add the defaults that do not exist.

```
var earliestDate = 1420070400000;
var latestDate = 1420329600000; // inclusive

(function(begin,end,increment){ 
  // faux array comprehension
  return Array.apply(null, {length: Math.floor((end+increment-begin)/increment)})
         .map(Number.call, function (n) {
            return begin + (n*increment);
         });
  })(earliestDate, latestDate, 86400000)
  .forEach(function (fillDate) {
    if( _.find(data,function (row) {
          return parseInt(row.date) === fillDate;
        }) === undefined){
      data.push({"date":fillDate.toString(),"value": 0,"lat": "no lat value","lon": "no lon value","regType": "no regType value","jobRole": "no jobRole value" });
    }
  });

console.log(data);
```

if you need it ordered by date, then you can **.sort** data after.
this isn't the most optimal way to do it, however it will work without changing your data structure.

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/96xmjf3x/

Comment: Yes, that worked beautifully, though it will take me some time studying it to grasp all of how you did it. And yes, ultimately I probably will want to sort these. There will be about 20000 rows eventually. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. The `date` in `data` is a string; you're comparing it against numbers. See http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/dst9nk6p/1/ for the easy fix.
2. The `list` array only has four elements, so you'll only get four values back. You're doing the map backwards; you want to iterate over `data`'s keys and check to see if they're in `list`.

This will make things inefficient if `list` gets big; you might want to put those values into a map as well so the array doesn't have to be iterated for each `data`.

Comment: 1) Ah, thanks for pointing out the strings/numbers! 2) I see. I reversed the data and list and am getting the correct number of objects! However I'm not sure what should go instead of { date: dateValue } on line 26. Right now it's putting a whole object there?  [A new JSFIDDLE] (http://jsfiddle.net/airwwwave/83cg11mL/)

Comment: @airwwwave If the size of the array can get big you should probably use a map, though, so you have O(1) valid date lookup; http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/9qcugpgy/

Comment: Thanks for your help, you got me pointed in the right direction. The answer above though is giving what I was after. Thank you!

Comment: I think I had an error in my original question and also may have been unclear. I have updated it to from "Note that the second date 1420156800000..." to "Note that the third date 1420243200000...". I need any missing dates that were not in the original array to be returned. In yours there is no object for the date 1420243200000. Sorry if I'm not being clear.